# Is there a way to stop an external door being slammed

Tags: doors

I live in a block of flats and we have an errant social housing tenant who gets in in the middle of the night and slams the front door.

We have a hydrolic door closer on the door - although only one with a single closing speed. Beyond adjusting the speed the door closes is there anything we can do to stop the door from being slammable?

Happy to spend maybe £500-1000 to fix this if that's what it takes.

Comment: What happens if he/she is being chased by a guy in a hockey mask?

Comment: I hate to burst your bubble, but while people in social housing are mostly constructive members of the community people who are drug addicts etc also land up there, and they are a pain to deal with. They then come back in the middle of the night and slam the doors and wake other residents up :(.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for a commercial grade door closer. One of those with a multi-stage closer mechanism can be adjusted so that the door closes gently but at the same time can keep it closed requiring some initial force to open the door. I am sure that there are many manufacturers of these closers. Here is an example picture of one.

[image]